woocommerce_checkout_order_processed posted_data not being received
Posted data being passed in 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed' hook does not get received at my function.  I checked in class-wc-checkout to make sure the data was present before the call.
This is the setup in my functions file:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wp_zlc_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed',10 );
function wp_zlc_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed($order_id,$posted_data=NULL,$order=NULL){


if I do not set the posted_data and $order vars to NULL then the code fails with:
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function wp_zlc_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed(), 1 passed ......
I have tried multiple senarios with no luck

Try this:
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'wp_zlc_woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 10, 3);

The reason for this is that because the action woocommerce_checkout_order_processed has 3 parameters, therefore in  add_action(), you need to add 3 at the end to indicate the number of parameters the function is passing through.
Reference: WP add_action() function

Thank you.  If I had read a little more carefully I would have seen that.

If that helps, please consider accepting my answer as the solution. Thanks!
